# Get document title from external page with Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dynamic

I'm a complete beginner in JavaScript / jQuery and I'm currently trying to achieve a goal rather than learn from scratch.

I have a dynamic webpage with separate links; these links do not refresh the page but refresh the content on the client's side. However, I don't *just* want to acquire and display the page *content*, **I want to replace the old title with the title of the newly loaded document** (for example, from "MySite | Home" to "MySite | About").

**JS/jQuery:**

```
$(function() {

if(Modernizr.history){

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $el;

$("a").click(function() {
    _link = $(this).attr("href");
    history.pushState(null, null, _link);
    loadContent(_link);
    return false;
});

function loadContent(href){
    $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(href + " #guts", document.title, function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200);
                    $("a").removeClass("current");
                    console.log(href);
                    $("a[href$="+href+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
}

$(window).bind('popstate', function(){
   _link = location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''); //get filename only
   loadContent(_link);
});

} // otherwise, history is not supported, so nothing fancy here.


});
```

**HTML:**

```
<header>
<h1>Dynamic Page</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
</header>
<section id="main-content">
<div id="guts">
<p>This is the homepage content</p>
</div>
</section>
```

Using the above personally-tweaked [third-party code from CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/): I've tried various additions **within** the  `function loadContent(href)` (underneath the `$myContent` section) such as:

```
$title.hide().load(href + document.title, function() {
$title.removeclass("current");
console.log(document.title);
$title[href$="document.title"]);
});
```

and

```
$title
.fadeOut(200, function() {
$title.hide().load(href + newTitle, function() {
newTitle.fadeIn(200);
});
```

(of which both result in an unwanted page refresh), alongside countless other attempts (apologies if these attempts are appalling - as I say, mainly trying to reach a goal at this current time and I wanted to show that I at least tried *something*).

**Any help or direction is greatly appreciated!!**

**UPDATE:** Please note this question has been updated as of 08/10/18. I realised a vital mistake within my example attempts that I thought may confuse potential respondents (I previously tried loading the document.title from within the mainContent section of the `function loadContent(href)`!).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your `'load'` will return, I suggest the following, here the server only sends the title as text:

```
$mainContent.hide().load(href + " #guts", document.title, function(responseText) {
                    document.title = responseText;
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200);
                    $("a").removeClass("current");
                    console.log(href);
                    $("a[href$="+href+"]").addClass("current");
                });
```

If instead your server sends a whole html page as response, then you can use the following:

```
$mainContent.hide().load(href + " #guts", document.title, function(responseText) {
                        document.title = $(responseText).find('title').text();
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200);
                        $("a").removeClass("current");
                        console.log(href);
                        $("a[href$="+href+"]").addClass("current");
                    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering!
I think I've realised a crucial mistake in my question.
Line 16 of my jQuery code `function loadContent(href){` only recalls information from within the 'main-content' section tag (defined in the jQuery as `$mainContent`) of the newly loaded document. I assume I would therefore have to create a separate entity within the `function loadContent(href){`  to acquire the `document.title` of the newly loaded document?
Apologies for the mistake and oversight!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way that solves the problem with dynamically changes title from external page with Javascript/jQuery?

```
$(function() {

if(Modernizr.history){

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $el;

$("a").click(function() {
    _link = $(this).attr("href");
    history.pushState(null, null, _link);
    loadContent(_link);
    return false;
});

function loadContent(href){
    $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(href + " #guts", function(loadTitle) {
                    document.title = loadTitle.match(/<title>([^<]*)/)[1];  
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200);
                    $("a").removeClass("current");
                    console.log(href);
                    $("a[href$="+href+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
}

$(window).bind('popstate', function(){
   _link = location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''); //get filename only
   loadContent(_link);
});

} // otherwise, history is not supported, so nothing fancy here.


});
```